# (Rails 5) Why is this integration test keyword params argument causing a deprecation warning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've tried adapting my post controller's integration test to conform to the Rails 5 keyword argument structure, but I continue to receive the deprecation warning. I've watched a couple videos and read through the documentation, but I still can't spot it. Any idea where I'm wrong in my syntax?

As a still-getting-my-feet-wet programmer, thank you in advance for the help! Please let me know if you'd like for me to share any other code snippets!

EDIT: Added deprecation warning

**Deprecation warning**

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest HTTP request methods will accept only
the following keyword arguments in future Rails versions:
params, headers, env, xhr, as

Examples:

get '/profile',
  params: { id: 1 },
  headers: { 'X-Extra-Header' => '123' },
  env: { 'action_dispatch.custom' => 'custom' },
  xhr: true,
  as: :json
 (called from non_kwarg_request_warning at /home/linux/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:309)
```

**posts_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user1 = users(:user1)
  end

  ....

  test "get posts index for authenticated users" do
    get login_path
    post sessions_path,
      params: { email: "user1@example.com",
                password: "password" }  

      # For some reason, use of the @user1 values does not log in the user...
      # params: { email: @user1.email,
      #           password: @user1.password_digest }

    get posts_path
    assert_response :success # Unauth user would redirect to login page
  end

end
```

**users.yml**

```
user1:
  name: user1
  email: user1@example.com
  password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create "password" %>

user2:
  name: user2
  email: user2@example.com
  password_digest: <%= BCrypt::Password.create "password" %>
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

....

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Log in successful!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password."
      render 'new'
    end
  end

....

end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    user_ids = current_user.timeline_user_ids
    @posts = Post.where(user_id: user_ids)
              .order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SessionsHelper
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

    def current_user
      if session[:user_id]
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
      end
    end
    helper_method :current_user

    def authenticate_user!
      redirect_to login_path unless current_user
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments
  resources :post_images
  resources :post_texts
  resources :posts
  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'

  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
  get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'

  root 'posts#index'
end
```

Comment: Can you please provide the specific depraction warning?

Comment: @slowjack2k Yes, added to the original post!

Comment: Without your spec, I would guess you have to use the `params` keyword like this  `post '/your/url', params: { ... your params ... }`

Comment: Hmm... The posts_controller_test.rb file should be listed under the Deprecation Warning in the original post. Here's the corresponding code snippet I used:

 post sessions_path,
      params: { email: "user1@example.com",
                      password: "password" }  

Surely it's not the formatting and code-spacing that's throwing it off...

Comment: I did see an example with `params` wrapped in curly braces that should work like this  `post sessions_path, { params: { email: "user1@example.com", password: "password" } }  `

Comment: @slowjack2k Beautiful, that did the trick! Just needed any extra set of curlies! Thank you for taking the time to help. If you post as an answer, I'll upvote and mark for you :)

While that outer set of curlies may be understood or implied by more experienced devs, as a newbie, I sure wish the Deprecation Warning included those extra brackets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your deprecation warning seems to have to do how Rails 5.0.0.1 detects keyword arguments. Why it happens, I don't know.

To satisfy this depraction warning, you need to wrap your paramters within curly braces. This way it is recognized as a `Hash` and satisfies Rails.

```
 post sessions_path, { params: { email: "user1@example.com", password: "password" } }
```